# Git becomes unversioned after changing iOS project name

Tags: ios, xcode, git, version-control

I have just changed my project name, for example from OldP to NewP.
Everything is fine except the version control.

I am using XCode 7 and iOS 9.

In Xcode - Version Editor, every file is showing "File is unversioned".

In command line, type `git status`, the result returned is like following:

```
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

           new file:   NewP.xcodeproj/project-bak.pbxproj.bak
           renamed:    OldP.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj -> NewP.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
           renamed:    OldP.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata -> NewP.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata
           new file:   NewP.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/xyz.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/xcschememanagement.plist
           deleted:    OldP.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/xyz.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/OldP.xcscheme

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

           modified:   NewP.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
           modified:   NewP.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/xyz.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/xcschememanagement.plist
           deleted:    OldP/AppDelegate.swift
           deleted:    OldP/Base.lproj/LaunchScreen.xib
           deleted:    OldP/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard
           ...
           ...
           ...
           ...
           ...

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

           NewP.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/xyz.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/NewP.xcscheme
           NewP.xcworkspace/
           NewP/
           NewPTests/
           Podfile
           Podfile.lock
           Pods/
```

If I do `git add .` and `git commit -m "after changing project name"`, the whole project is versioned again.

In "Source Control" -> "History", I can still see every revision history in there, including the latest committed one.

However, in "Version Editor", there are only two revisions: "Local Revision" and the latest committed revision. No more previous revisions before changing the project name to be shown up here.

Type `git diff filename`, nothing will be shown up.

I know the issue here is because in git repository, the project name in previous revisions history is still "OldP", so when comparing versions for the new project name "NewP", it won't show up previous revisions for "OldP".

Could anyone please suggest how to fix this issue, so I can still see every previous revisions in my new named project?

Thanks.

Comment: please look this link may help you
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46037148/1496321)

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue by using `git filter-branch --tree-filter`