# Git - Xcode files are scheduled for Deletion in Project Navigator 'D'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, git, bitbucket

I was implementing some feature using Core Data, when I added a xcdatamodeld file, all my Xcode's files in the project navigator become with a 'D' icon. When I deleted the xcdatamodeld file, some files change their symbol to '?'.

I did some research and I found that 'D' means that the item/file is scheduled for Deletion. When I tried to see the git status using the terminal, all my project files was deleted.

Someone please can help me to commit my project without losing my Xcode files ?

Any help would be appreciated :)

PS: I'm using Xcode version 9.0 beta 4, and Bitbucket server.

Here is a screenshot of my project navigator:

[image]

And here is a screenshot of my terminal:

[image]

Comment: Don't worry xcode's version control always gets confused. I also observed unexpected source control indicators in xcode, but when I run `git status` in terminal it gives the correct state.

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov, when I run git status in terminal, it displays deleted state. I'm afraid if I commit my project all my files will be deleted in Bitbucket.

Answer (score 7):

To unstage deleting a file use `git reset HEAD filename.ext` from the command line.